# Check to see if string is subset of another string plus a minor digit in the begining in perl

Tags: regex, perl, grep, substitution

I am trying to see if a string1 is in string2 in perl

```
$Item1="I Like Coffee";
$Item2="2 I Like Coffee";
$Item3="I like Milke";

$Item1=$Item2 but $Item1!=$item3
```

One way to do it is to strip out the 2 at the beginning of the $item2 and then compare. As follows:

```
$item=~s/(\d+)//;
```

Then we can compare.
Rather the better way would be to grep for Item1 in the Item2 and if true do the rest. But grep works only on lists, Is there subtle way to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (index(STRING,SUBSTRING) >= 0) and print "SUBSTRING in STRING\n" ;
```

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for there is also a substr function in perl as well. Great!

Answer (score 1):

Andrey's question solves part of your actual question. `index` will tell you whether or not that sub-string exists in the pattern, but the way he answered it it could return the same verdict for the two strings being exactly equal.

```
sub majics_match {
    my ( $look, $cand ) = @_;
    return 1 unless length( $look // '' );
    return 0 unless length( $cand // '' );
    my $pos = index( $cand, $look );
    return 0 unless $pos > 0;
    return substr( $cand, 0, $pos ) =~ m/^\d\s+/ 
        && substr( $cand, $pos + length( $look )) eq ''
        ;
}
```

...OR you could do this with a regex:

```
$cand =~ m/^\d \Q$look\E$/;
```